# Generate matrices whose null spaces are non-zero integer vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices

I am trying to generate 500 matrices whose null spaces are non-zero, integer vectors.

I currently generate the matrices by using `rand()` to choose a number between 1 and 5. I find the kernel by passing the matrix to EigenLib's `kernel()` function. However, my matrix generation algorithm is entirely insufficient because (generally) 19/20 of the kernels are the zero vector.

How do I generate matrices whose null spaces will have integer, non-zero vectors?

Comment: Should the null spaces have a specific dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First choose a column vector $v$ with integer entries that is to be in the null space.  Then find a matrix whose rows are orthogonal to $v$.  The simplest case will be if some element $v_k$ of $v$ is $\pm 1$.  Then you can choose the entries $a_{ij}$ for $j \ne k$ randomly, and
take $a_{ik} = \mp \sum_{j \ne k} a_{ij} v_j$.

Comment: Just trying to understand...a matrix, M, orthogonal to v, will mean that `M x v = 0`. What is the difference between `aij` and `aik` in your example?

Comment: $a_{ik}$ is the element that will multiply $v_k$, which is $\pm 1$.

Comment: For example, if your matrices are $3 \times 3$ and $v = \pmatrix{3\cr 2\cr 1\cr}$, you take $a_{i3} = - 3 a_{i1} - 2 a_{i2}$, where $a_{i1}$ and $a_{i2}$ are any integers.